# Add values to List of objects in C#

Tags: c#, object, addition

Need to add values to the below object. Should be able to add for a `student`, list of `subjects`.

Created two `university` objects which is of type list and then trying to add values

```
    public class university
    {
        public int student;
        public IList<subject> subjects;
    }

    public class subject
    {
        public string text;
        public int id;
    };
```

What is the best approach

Comment: When you ask "what is the best", you're asking for an opinion. For various reasons that's not beneficial for users in general.

Comment: Your question is not clear, Add more details, explain your objects, give context, show what you are trying to achieve and what if you tried something, show it as well

Answer (score -1):

This may help you.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var university = new University()
        {
            Student = 1,
            Subjects = new List<Subject>()
            {
                new Subject() { Id = 1, Text = "Math" },

                new Subject() { Id = 2, Text = "English" },
            },

        };
    }
}

public class University
{
    public int Student { get; set; }

    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; } = new List<Subject>();
}

public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
};
```

Comment: Please explain how this "may help [them]".

Comment: I just try to give a simple solution for this question. And I don't know @user3676367 level of knowledge.